# Making an IRC bot - how can I let people !eval perl/javascript code?

Tags: perl, irc, evaluation, poe

I'm working on a bot in Perl (based on POE) and so far so good, but I can't figure out how can I add a `!js` or `!perl` command to evaluate respective code and return one line of output to be printed into the channel. I found [App::EvalServer](http://search.cpan.org/~hinrik/App-EvalServer-0.08/lib/App/EvalServer.pm) but I don't get how to use it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `!perl system('rm -rf /')` - this is not the best idea imho, but in a save environment it might be ok.

Comment: Be careful when evaluating code. You can't trust user input. Only evaluate code on a safe, distant environment, or only allow trusted people to do it.

Comment: Thing is, I don't even know how to do it. I don't know how to evaluate Perl/JS code in Perl. :/

Comment: @argoneus That's probably a good thing! Allowing people to `eval` arbitrary perl code sounds like a horribly unsafe idea. All it takes is one user having a bad password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `App::EvalServer` module comes with a binary to run as a [standalone application](http://search.cpan.org/~hinrik/App-EvalServer-0.08/bin/evalserver). You do not put it in your program but rather run it on it's own. It opens a port where you can hand it code as a json string. This does not sound like a good idea to me either.

There is another module you might want to look at called [Safe](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Safe-2.33/Safe.pm). I suggest you read through the complete documentation as well as the one to [Opcode](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/ext/Opcode/Opcode.pm) (linked in the doc) before you do anything with this. **YOU CAN DO SERIOUS DAMAGE IF YOU EVALUATE ARBITRARY CODE!** Never forget that.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example of how to capture the output of `print` or `say` from your `eval`ed code. You can use [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) with a variable to make `print`ed output always go to that variable. If you switch back afterwards you can work with the captured output in your var. This is called an *in-memory file*.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say'; 
use Safe;

# Put our STDOUT into a variable
my $printBuffer;
open(my $buffer, '>', \$printBuffer);
# Everything we say and print will go into $printBuffer until we change it back
my $stdout = select($buffer);

# Create a new Safe
my $compartment = new Safe;
$compartment->permit(qw(print)); # for testing

# This is where the external code comes in:
my $external_code = qq~print "Hello World!\n"~;

# Execute the code
my $ret = $compartment->reval($external_code, 1);

# Go back to STDOUT
select($stdout);

printf "The return value of the reval is: %d\n", $ret;
say "The reval's output is:";
say $printBuffer;

# Now you can do whatever you want with your output
$printBuffer =~ s/World/Earth/;
say "After I change it:";
say $printBuffer;
```

Disclaimer: **Use this code at your own risk!**

---

**Update 2**: After a lengthy discussion in chat, here's what we came up with. It implements a kind of timeout to stop the execution if the `reval` is taking to long, e.g. because of an infinite loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Safe;
use Benchmark qw(:hireswallclock);

my ($t0, $t1); # Benchmark
my $timedOut = 0;
my $userError = 0;
my $printBuffer;
open (my $buffer, '>', \$printBuffer);
my $stdout = select($buffer);
my $cpmt = new Safe;
$cpmt->permit_only(qw(:default :base_io sleep));
eval
{
        local $SIG{'ALRM'} = sub { $timedOut = 1; die "alarm\n"};
        $t0 = Benchmark->new;
        alarm 2;
        $cpmt->reval('print "bla\n"; die "In the user-code!";');
#         $cpmt->reval('print "bla\n"; sleep 50;');
        alarm 0;
        $t1 = Benchmark->new;
        if ($@)
        {
                $userError = "The user-code died! $@\n";
        }
};
select($stdout);


if ($timedOut)
{
        print "Timeout!\n";
        my $td = timediff($t1, $t0);
        print timestr($td), "\n";
        print $printBuffer;
}
else
{
        print "There was no timeout...\n";
        if ($userError)
        {
                print "There was an error with your code!\n";
                print $userError;
                print "But here's your output anyway:\n";
                print $printBuffer;
        }
        else
        {
          print $printBuffer;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this, but when I did !perl print "bla", it printed 'bla' only in my console.. I was using the opcodes :default and :base_io. Any idea why?

Comment: I think this depends on your definition of eval. If you want it to print stuff to IRC, you need to tell it to do that. When you eval a print in the `Safe`, it will most likely not print that to your IRC connection. You need to catch what the eval says and send that to the IRC. Again, **be careful**! With this it might also be possible to find weaknesses in your software if the right code is `eval`ed.

Comment: Well, I did `$result = $compartment->reval($code)` and then sent `$result` to IRC, but when I do !perl print "bla", instead of printing "bla" on irc it prints "1". But when I `print $result` in my bot before sending it to irc, it shows the correct output "bla".. Any idea why could that be?

Comment: In the [doc](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Safe-2.33/Safe.pm#reval_%28STRING,_STRICT%29) it says *"the method returns the value of the last expression evaluated"*, which in case of `print` is 1 if the `print` succeeded. You could try opening a filehandle to write to a variable in your outside code, use `[share](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Safe-2.33/Safe.pm#share_%28NAME,_...%29)` to get that into the compartment and replace the `eval`'s `STDOUT` with it each time you `eval` something.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I have no idea what you mean >.<

Comment: I'll change my post. It's actually a bit simpler than what I first thought.

Comment: What exactly does `my $stdout = select($buffer);` do? The way I understand is that when you later to `select($stdout);` you will re-switch to `$buffer`, no?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [perl eval()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), you can pass it variables/strings and it will evaluate it as if it's perl code. Likewise in javascript, there's also an [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function that performs similarly.

However, **DO NOT EVALUATE ARBITRARY CODE** in either perl or javascript unless you can run it in a completely closed environment (and even then, it's still a bad idea). Lot's of people spend lots of time [preventing just this from happening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution). So that's how you'd do it, but you don't want to do it, really at all.

Comment: No, but you can run the [jsc](http://www.phpied.com/javascript-shell-scripting/) command and eval javascript that way.

Comment: @argoneus See the jsc link, you can do: `jsc -e bla`, or write it to a file and pass it to jsc, etc.

Comment: I mean how can I call jsc from perl?

Comment: @argoneus you can also use [JavaScript::SpiderMonkey](https://metacpan.org/module/JavaScript::SpiderMonkey).